# C# SQL Command parameter not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've done some trouble shooting by taking out the parameters and replacing them with text, and the only parameter that is not working is @seat and I can't figure out why.

allSeats is an array of custom controls. I've tried replacing the parameter contents with an actual string ie. "A1" and that still doesn't work. If I remove the @seat parameter and replace it with A1, it works, but I need to be able to set the column name dynamically.

```
myConnection.Open();

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Events SET @seat = @truefalse WHERE Name = @name", myConnection);

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@seat";
param2.ParameterName = "@truefalse";
param2.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Boolean;
param3.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value = allSeats[i].Name;
param2.Value = allSeats[i].taken;
param3.Value = name;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param2);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param3);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help is appreciated. If I need to post more relevant code please let me know and I shall add it.

Comment: Is `@seat` supposed to be a dynamic column name? If so, you will need to use dynamic SQL to make this work.

Comment: Is seat a completely dynamic column name, or will it be one of a fixed number of options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your

```
SET @seat = @truefalse
```

part, you try to parameterize your column name. You can't do that. You only can parameterize your values, not column name or table names.

You can use dynamic SQL for such a case but it is not recommended. Read

- [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [SELECT * FROM @tablename](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table)

As a recommendation, use a white list such a case. I hope, there can only be a fixed set of *possible* correct values for the column name. Of course, this requires strong validation in your inputs part.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware you couldn't use parameters for column names. I've just gone ahead and concatenated allSeats[i].Name into the command string instead.
I knew I could do that the whole time I was just intent on getting this to work, Lol.
Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @user3217010 Your are quite welcome. Yes, parameters only for values. If you _really_ want to get your column or table names, always use a white list with a strong recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Soner. Change the string before you create the command

```
string cmdStr = string.Format("UPDATE Events SET {0} = @truefalse WHERE Name = @name",  allSeats[i].Name)
```

Then 
only use 2 parameters.

```
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, myConnection);
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.parameter.addwithvalue("@param1", value1);

cmd.parameter.addwithvalue("@param2", value2);
```

use like this.

Comment: my mistake. i got your question now

Answer (score 0):

As Soner has mentioned, columns cannot be parameterized. This means you will either have to create dynamic queries, or create all the parameterized once at the startup, one query per column name.

this can be done in the following example:

```
private static Dictionary<string, SqlCommand>  parameterizedCommands = new Dictionary<string,SqlCommand>();

public static void CreateparameterizedCommandsy(string[] colums)
{
    parameterizedCommands = new Dictionary<string,SqlCommand>();
    foreach (string colname in colums)
    {
        parameterizedCommands.Add(colname, CreateCommandForColumn(colname));
    }
}

public static SqlCommand CreateCommandForColumn(string columnName)
{
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE Events SET {0} = @truefalse WHERE Name = @name",columnName));
    // the following statement creates the parameter in one go. Bit = boolean
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@truefalse", SqlDbType.Bit);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text);
    return myCommand;
}


public int ExccuteColumnUpdate(string columnName, bool setToValue, string name, SqlConnection connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand command;
        if (parameterizedCommands.TryGetValue(columnName, out command))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Parameters["@truefalse"].Value = setToValue;
            command.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```